# Replacing a button with a link

Tags: php, html, css

Ok i have this code that works:

```
echo '<input name="edit'.$i.'" type="submit" value="Edit" />';
$edit_button="edit".$i;

if (isset($_POST[$edit_button]))
```

But now I'm using a admin template/css with a css class that I want to use and it only works with links or the `<a>` tag. How can I transform the above code to work with this:

```
echo '<a href="" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a>';
```

Basically I want to see if the link was clicked but refresh to the same page, I think I can do this with $_GET but I'm not sure how, any advice?

Comment: Create a new css class. Copy the code to it. Change the class of the submit button to that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work ;)

```
echo '<a href="thesamepage.php?button=5" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a>';

if(isset($_GET['button'])&&$_GET['button']==5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="?edit_button=1" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip">Edit</a>

<?php

if (!empty($_GET['edit_button'])) {
    // your actions
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `!empty()` and `isset()`?

Comment: `isset()` **Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL** `empty()` **Determine whether a variable is empty**

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "href" attribute as "script.php?var=val". And then work with $_GET['var']